# Magento Show Attribute Option after Filteration process done

Tags: magento

I am facing one problem i want to show Attribute option after filtering process done.

Suppose there are 3 colors in shop by block

```
1 Read(5)
2 Blue(6)
3 Green(10)
```

Now Suppose i am clicking on Green(10) link from shop by block it will display all the product which contain Green colors,It's right but after getting filtering result colors option didn't show again but when i click on clear All link it will show all Attribute option but i not what to this!

Instead of this all color option should show as it is after filtering process done!

like once i click on Green(10) link after filtering process done i want to show all color option again!

same as before filtration process

like this

```
1 Read(5)
2 Blue(6)
3 Green(10)
```

does any one have any idea how to do this!

I am kindly waiting for your valuable response.

Thanks in advance......